# How to modify sonarlint rules in Intellij configuration

Tags: intellij-idea, sonarqube, sonarlint, sonarlint-intellij

I want to disable some of the sonarlint rules on my Intellij for my team. I know one way to do it is

> File -> Settings -> Other Settings -> SonarLint General Settings

, and then checking/un-checking each rule one by one, but I want to do it in one shot. I don't want my entire team to do this check un-check individually. Is there a way to modify local sonarlint file for Intellij ? If I can do that, I can share the same rule file across team.

Answer (score 1):

Use SonarLint in connected mode with a SonarQube server. This way, all the rule configurations will be shared with everyone connected to the same server.